# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit' discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi guys I have a problem that I think is trivial but I don't understand why I saved a message that I send (interacion.send_message.response) in a variable to then be able to edit the message with variablename.edit only that even with sending the message success the variable remains None and prevents me from editing the message...How do I fix it?
[the code: (if the code as image is a problem tell me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQQJo.png)

The code should simply modify the embed sent with another message after pressing the button the problem is that in the function: "async def commands" the message is saved correctly but when it returns to the callback of the button (or class) "nextcallback" the message becomes empty (None)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: Also, take the [tour], search for the error message online and include a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [`InteractionResponse.send_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=send_message#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message) show that it doesn't return anything, so you can't expect anything other than `None` to come out of it.

To fetch your response, you can use [`Interaction.original_response()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=send_message#discord.Interaction.original_response):

> Fetches the original interaction response message associated with the interaction.
>
> **If the interaction response was a newly created message (i.e. through InteractionResponse.send_message()** or InteractionResponse.defer(), where thinking is True) **then this returns the message that was sent using that response.**